# Windows Server 2008 VM - network services failing

Tags: hyper-v

I would really appreciated another perspective on an issue we have been experiencing.

**The environment:**

We have a small subset of VMs (5 Windows Server 2008 R2 VM's) hosted on a Windows Server 2012 Cluster of 8 Physical Hosts which supports 100's over VMs across various OS (2008/2012 etc).

**The issue:**

Servers within the subset of VMs experience widespread network SERVICE failures. The failure presents itself as a loss in connectivity for a large number of network related services operating on the VMs (including certain critical network dependant applications).

**The impacts:**

Server remains online.

Inability to RDP to the servers via Domain Accounts (Local accounts are fine).

Windows event logs associated with Netlogon Failure: Event ID 5719 - This computer was not able to set up a secure session with a domain controller in domain DOWNERGROUP due to the following: 
The RPC server is unavailable. This may lead to authentication problems.

Windows event logs assocaited with Group Policy Failure:

> Event ID 1054:The processing of Group Policy failed. Windows could not
>   obtain the name of a domain controller. This could be caused by a name
>   resolution failure. Verify your Domain Name System (DNS) is configured
>   and working correctly

Widespread Agent Failure (AV, Monitoring, Application) - Lack of connectivty to centralised management servers.

The resolution(s). Stopping an agent service. Strange however its not limited to a specific agent however if we stop agent A, the server comes back to life, however if we also stop agent B, the server comes back to life with Agent A still running. Restarting the VM also resolves the issue.

Note that these events do not appear on other VMs hosted off the same host at the time of the outage. Also note that the guest is located on the same host prior to, during and after the outage.

We have investigated the suspicion that their may be issues with Dynamic Range Port Allocation with the server possibly getting into a bottleneck state. We have implementedthe "MaxUserPort" and "TCPTimedWaitDelay" registry parameters and have set them to 65k and 30 respectively.

Also note that when an outage occurs, it does not always occur on the same VMs in the group. Often times it is 2, 3, 4 or all servers.

Im really just asking if anyone can see these symptoms and relate to possible causes for our situation.

Any help/discussion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this turned out to be an interesting resolution.

We discovered that one of our server agents, while not actually showing open ports in Netstat, had over 40,000 handles growing linearly over time.

Had to enable the "handles" column in task manager to be able to see this info.

This was the miracle post...
http://blogs.technet.com/b/kimberj/archive/2012/07/06/sever-quot-hangs-quot-and-ephemeral-port-exhaustion-issues.aspx